# Problem on random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

**Problem**

John has two cows, Cindy and Sally. The amount of liters per day that Cindy gives is a random variable $X \sim \mathcal E(0,2)$. Sally gives $5$ liters per day $20$% of the time she is milked and the remaining $80$% she gives nothing. John milks Sally just the days in which Cindy gives less than $6$ liters of milk.

1) Calculate the probability of Cindy giving more than $6$ liters per day in exactly two days of the week.

2) Calculate the probability of John obtaining more than $8$ liters of milk in a day.

I think I could solve part 1) of the problem but I don't know what to do in 2), I'll write what I could think of:

1) I'll call a success to the event "Cindy gives more that $6$ liters per day" and a failure to its complement. If I call $p=P(X > 6)$ and I consider the binomial random variable $Y \sim Bi(7,p)$, then the probability in 1) is exactly $$P(Y=2)={7 \choose 2}p^2(1-p)5$$

I am not sure if this solution is correct, as for $2)$ I am pretty lost, I would appreciate suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that John only milks Sally if Cindy gives strictly less than 6 litres of milk a day, so $p = P(X \geq 6)$. Otherwise, your solution to part 1 is correct (mind the exponent at the end!)

For part 2, your expected amount of milk is the amount of milk Cindy gives in addition to the probability that John milks Sally times the amount of milk Sally gives. You'll have to multiply the probabilities by the actual amount of milk Cindy and Sally give, which is just $X$ and $Z$, where $Z$ is a discrete random variable $P(Z = 0) = 0.8$ and $P(Z = 5) = 0.2$.

$$
M = X + P(X < 6) \times Z
$$

Now you want to find the probability that $M > 8$ on a given day, and that's it!

(By the way, what probability distribution is $\mathcal E(0,2)$? I've never seen it before.)